# wordpress submit for review instead of update on page for author user?

Tags: wordpress

I'd like to get "submit for review" for author user when they want to updating or changing into a page.
This is my code which works only after clicking on update button then it will show "Submit for review". I don't want to update button on page when author user is working on this. Thanks.

```
function postPending($post_ID) { 

$c_user = wp_get_current_user();

    if( $c_user->user_login == "user1")

   //if(get_role('author')) {

      remove_action('post_updated', 'postPending', 10, 3);

     return wp_update_post(array('ID' => $post_ID, 'post_status' => 'pending review' ));

     add_action( 'post_updated', 'postPending', 10, 3 );
   }
 }

 add_action('post_updated', 'postPending', 10, 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code and put this into `function.php`.

```
add_action( 'init', function() {
    $author_role = get_role( 'author' );
   $author_role->add_cap('publish_posts');
   $author_role->add_cap('edit_posts',true);
} );
function postPending($post_ID,$post_after,$post_before)
 {  
    $display_name = get_the_modified_author();
    global $wpdb;

    $user = $wpdb->get_row( $wpdb->prepare(
        "SELECT `ID` FROM $wpdb->users WHERE `display_name` = %s", $display_name
    ) );
    $user_meta = get_userdata($user->ID);
    $user_roles=$user_meta->roles;

     if(in_array('author', $user_roles))
     {
        //Unhook this function
        remove_action('post_updated', 'postPending', 10, 3);

        return wp_update_post(array('ID' => $post_ID, 'post_status' => 'pending'));

        // re-hook this function
        add_action( 'post_updated', 'postPending', 10, 3 );
     }
 }
add_action('post_updated', 'postPending', 10, 3);
```

Do let me know the result.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it is not working, when we remove cap "edit_posts"  , it shows only frontend user account page.  i want to change that update button on dashboard page editor.

Comment: Thanks.. but still it is showing first Update button, and after clicking on this it shows Submit for review button. I want Submit for review button only. Also  i am using User Role Editor Plugin.   Please check if there is any other option in this plugin.. i am using free version of this plugin.

Comment: We have only this way to do so as you will remove the cap for edit_posts than the authors will not able to open admin panels.

Comment: yes, you are right. but i need admin panel also. is there any capability for update button ?